# How to get single column values using MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to get list or emails in a one-dimensional array from MySQL database.
However, I am getting multidimensional array, rather then array:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT `EmailAddress` FROM `Emails` WHERE `JobID` = 1";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result) {
    printf("Query failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$result->close();
$conn->close();
var_dump($rows); // This will return array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "abc@abc.com" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "hello@gmail.com" } }
//This is how array should be
$MyV = array("abc@abc.com", "hello@gmail.com");
var_dump($MyV); //this is an array I need to have: array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "Abc@abc.com" [1]=> string(11) "hello@g.com" }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $rows[]=$row['EmailAddress'];
}
```

Comment: fetch_assoc is rather superfluous here, you need to know the exact column name. with fetch_row it's simpler, shorter and universally applicable to any query

Answer (score 4):

The answers above are correct, but here's an example with minimum code modifications to your current source.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
  $rows[]=$row[0];
}
```

Now `$rows` will be a one dimensional array populated with email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend one of the following three options:

1. You could use `foreach` and insert just the column you need into a new array.

   ```
   foreach ($result as $row) {
       $emailAddresses[] = $row['EmailAddress'];
   }
   ```
2. You can use `fetch_all()` with `array_column()`

   ```
   $emailAddresses = array_column($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC), 'EmailAddress');
   ```
3. Using `fetch_column()`:

   ```
   while($email = $result->fetch_column()) {
       $emailAddresses[] = $email;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

At this point in your loop, you have access to the simple array you are talking about.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
  $rows[]=$row;
}
```

So if you want to do anything with that array assign it to some variable or call a function with the array, something like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    doSomethingFun($row);
}
```